# Database Mail to Distribution List

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I have a SQL Server 2005 which I have configured the database mail to setup monitoring alerts and notifications. I also create a email distribution list containing a couple of emails. The thing is that when I send the email from the database to a distribution list, it never gets to the emails inbox, but if I do it individually it does.

I tried to send an email from the outlook to the distribution list and it worked fine. I do not understand what is happening. Please can you help me?

Comment: Did you restart SQL Agent?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

Odds are the the account with which the Database Mail profile is logging into the SMTP server doesn't have rights within Exchange to send to the distribution list.  You need to work with your exchange admin to see what's going on within the Exchange server.  There are tracing tools within Exchange they can use to see exactly what's going on.